# How to use all the memory in python on a mutlinodes supercomputer?

Tags: python, linux, hpc

I use a supercomputer to fit a sklearn model. System info:

```
Linux ito-2 3.10.0-514.26.2.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Jun 30 05:26:04 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

The supercomputer has 4 nodes, and each node has 180GB memory. However, when I run

```
import psutil
psutil.virtual_memory()
```

It returns

```
svmem(total=201256185856, available=196754653184, percent=2.2, used=3810926592, free=197162655744, active=229847040, inactive=200900608, buffers=7401472, cached=275202048, shared=21483520, slab=547241984)
```

Obviously, that only counts a single node. The python environment does have so much memory, and my  code keeping failing.

How to allocate all the memory in 4 nodes to python.

Thank you.

Comment: Supercomputers cannot easily be used as 1 machine for such application. There are tools to abstract multiple nodes (eg. distributed shared memory) but they are generally either not possible to use in this context, tricky to use/install or simply far too slow. In fact, this is not how HPC application works. You need to **distribute** the work of your application on multiple nodes. Tools like MPI are really the basics for that (and very widely used). [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73014898) related recent post talk about this (Numba can be replaced by SciPy in your context)

Comment: By the way, the comment about optimization also apply and is especially important in your case as SciPy is known to consume a significant amount of memory compared to plain C application. Additionally, using 4 nodes of a supercomputer for a sequential process would be clearly wasting resources. Consider out-of-core methods for that. In fact, I think mapped memory of very fast NVMe SSDs (or even non-volatile memory) can do a better job than DSM on supercomputer nodes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to start looking for a dOS (distributed operating system) or something like that. (look into [OpenNebula](https://opennebula.io/))

You also can split your workloads and use cluster computing tools to let them manage your workloads (eg. Kubernetes)

It all depends on what you want to do and what path you are ready to take on.

Comment: Now, I use sklearn to run a random forest, the model has over 180GB. I just want it to be able to fit normally, without error. Is it possible? Thanks.

Comment: @ChaoLi I dont know much AI, but you dont have to load the whole 180GB data set into memory. think about ways to split your workload into chunks. Its pretty hard to consolidate systems into one.

Comment: Supercomputers have a restricted set of installed tools. I never saw any large supercomputer with OpenNebula or Kubernetes used. This is more Cloud-related tools and I am not aware of admin admin that will allow this. In fact, a significant part of supercomputers do not have a direct internet access for security reasons and even critical tools like an up to date compiler or profiling tools are missing. In nearly all supercomputers, users do not have (true) root access (still for security reasons) so they cannot use such tools. Compiling tools is sometime possible but tedious and even tricky.